# Groovy Ant Task NoSuchMethodError

Tags: maven, groovy, ant

I am experimenting with groovy ant tasks and keep encountering this weird version mismatch.
All I want to achieve is for the groovy task to execute code from an external file.

**my setup:**

files:

```
C:\tmp\groovy-ant-test\ 
   |_pom.xml
   |_task.groovy
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                <echo message="compile classpath: ${compile_classpath}" />

                                <taskdef resource="org/codehaus/groovy/antlib.xml">
                                    <classpath refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                                </taskdef>
                                <groovy>
                                    println "Hello from pom.xml!"
                                </groovy>
                                <groovy src="task.groovy" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-ant</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

task.groovy

```
println "Hello from task.groovy!"
```

**my expectations:**

```
[...]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) @ test ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] compile classpath: C:\tmp\groovy-ant-test\target\classes;M:\org\apache\groovy\groovy\4.0.6\groovy-4.0.6.jar;M:\org\apache\groovy\groovy-ant\4.0.6\groovy-ant-4.0.6.jar;M:\org\apache\ant\ant-junit\1.10.12\ant-junit-1.10.12.jar;M:\org\apache\ant\ant-launcher\1.10.12\ant-launcher-1.10.12.jar;M:\org\apache\ant\ant-antlr\1.10.12\ant-antlr-1.10.12.jar;M:\org\apache\groovy\groovy-groovydoc\4.0.6\groovy-groovydoc-4.0.6.jar;M:\org\apache\ant\ant\1.10.12\ant-1.10.12.jar;C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\8.322.06.1\lib\tools.jar
Hello from pom.xml!
Hello from task.groovy!

[...]
```

**my result:**

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) @ test ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] compile classpath: C:\tmp\groovy-ant-test\target\classes;M:\org\apache\groovy\groovy\4.0.6\groovy-4.0.6.jar;M:\org\apache\groovy\groovy-ant\4.0.6\groovy-ant-4.0.6.jar;M:\org\apache\ant\ant-junit\1.10.12\ant-junit-1.10.12.jar;M:\org\apache\ant\ant-launcher\1.10.12\ant-launcher-1.10.12.jar;M:\org\apache\ant\ant-antlr\1.10.12\ant-antlr-1.10.12.jar;M:\org\apache\groovy\groovy-groovydoc\4.0.6\groovy-groovydoc-4.0.6.jar;M:\org\apache\ant\ant\1.10.12\ant-1.10.12.jar;C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\8.322.06.1\lib\tools.jar
Hello from pom.xml!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.425 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-24T13:49:36+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) on project test: An Ant BuildException has occured: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tools.ant.filters.util.ChainReaderHelper.<init>(Lorg/apache/tools/ant/Project;Ljava/io/Reader;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)V
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<groovy src="task.groovy"/>... @ 10:30 in C:\tmp\groovy-ant-test\target\antrun\build-main.xml
```

additional stacktrace part from -X option:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tools.ant.filters.util.ChainReaderHelper.<init>(Lorg/apache/tools/ant/Project;Ljava/io/Reader;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)V
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy.readCommandFromReader (Groovy.java:432)
```

The maven classpath contains groovy-ant:4.0.6, which depends on ant:1.10.12 which i have explicitly provided.
org.apache.tools.ant.filters.util.ChainReaderHelper in ant:1.10.12 has a constructor with the requred args.

I dont see the possibility of wrong versions on the classpath, as dependency:tree shows

```
[INFO] test:test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.groovy:groovy:jar:4.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.groovy:groovy-ant:jar:4.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ant:ant-junit:jar:1.10.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.10.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ant:ant-antlr:jar:1.10.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.groovy:groovy-groovydoc:jar:4.0.6:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.10.12:compile
[INFO]    \- com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0:system
```

Are there any reasons for failure that I don't see, or have I misconfigured something?

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging of the antrun plugin I found out the maven-antrun-plugin itself was contributing the wrong ant version (1.9.4 in this case).

a change to

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
```

leads to the desired output.